# Como manipular o volume do áudio em tempo real

Tags: python-3.x, áudio, dsp

Como eu posso manipular o volume desse áudio em tempo real ?

```
import time, pydub, numpy as np, sounddevice as sd, random

file_path = '/path/to/file.mp3'

def read(f, normalized=False):
    a = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(f)

    y = np.array(a.get_array_of_samples())
    if a.channels == 2:
        y = y.reshape((-1, 2))
    if normalized:
        return a.frame_rate, np.float32(y) / 2**15
    else:
        return a.frame_rate, y

data, fs = read(file_path)

sd.play(data, fs)
#sd.play(data * 20, fs) // eu só sei que se eu multiplicar eu consigo aumentar ou diminuir o volume, não consegui chegar em nada além disso

while(True):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: e vc pensa em alterar o volume como ? usando alguma tecla para diminuir ou aumentar o volume em tempo real ?

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada nessa biblioteca: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub

```
#Make the beginning louder and the end quieter

# boost volume by 6dB
beginning = first_10_seconds + 6

# reduce volume by 3dB
end = last_5_seconds - 3
```

Comment: O problema é que depois que eu dei play no audio `sd.play(data, fs)` eu não consigo mais alterar o volume, e eu preciso alterar o volume enquanto o áudio está tocando.

Answer (score 1):

Eu marquei para responder essa pergunta faz tempo mas nunca tive tempo (hj tive tempo rsrs)...

Para trabalhar em tempo real com áudios você precisa imaginar como alterar cada pedaço do seu arquivo e enviar para o dispositivo de saída de som...

Você precisará trabalhar com [AudioCallback](https://www.reddit.com/r/DSP/comments/53t2k3/whats_an_audio_callback_function/)(uma explicação legal em inglês), ou construir um loop que consiga fazer stream de pedaços de áudio, nesse loop a cada iteração você será capaz de mudar o volume do som via alguma interface com o usuário(teclado, algum botão) ...

Para a nossa sorte Python tem um módulo incrível chamado [Pyaudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/), assim poderemos decodificar o áudio e passar para o Pyaudio fazer stream, permitindo alterar cada pedaço de áudio que desejar antes de despejar no buffer de saída!

Se quiser algo com melhor desempenho é possível trabalhar com callback no Pyaudio...

Mas vamos ao que interessa, ao código, eu fiz aqui para demonstrar como isso funciona dentro de um looping em python, estou usando a sua função com `normalized=True` para manter o arquivo decodificado em float point, estou testando em solo windows então para interação com usuário estou carregando um módulo chamado [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) esse módulo me permite utilizar a função `getch()` para capturar as teclas pressionadas pelo usuário do windows, como estou dentro de um `for` a cada iteração poderei verificar se alguma tecla foi pressionada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento estou usando a seta para cima código da tecla = `18656` para incrementar o volume e seta para baixo código da tecla = `20704` para decrementar o volume...

O `For` vai caminhar por todo o áudio, para cada iteração é feita a checagem das teclas e é separado um pedaço do áudio com 4096 amostras, isso será feito até o `for` percorrer todo o arquivo decodificado!

Para cada iteração um pedaço de áudio é separado do vetor e é aplicado a multiplicação do volume, usei um fator de `0.1` para cada decremento ou incremento, logo após eu estou "clipando" o áudio, removendo qualquer amplitude que extrapole os valores do `float point (-1 e 1)` e finalmente o áudio é encapsulado e enviado para o Pyaudio tocar o pedaço alterado(stream), como esse tipo de processamento é baixo (só calcular um novo volume) não existe gaps entre cada frame no loop, e assim a mágica de alterar o volume em tempo real acontece, pense em fazer agora coisas mais complexas com áudio + python em tempo real ...

Código completo:

```
from struct import pack
import pydub, numpy as np
import pyaudio
import msvcrt


file_path = 'Joe_Satriani_-_Starry_Night.mp3'

def read(f, normalized=True):
    a = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(f)

    y = np.array(a.get_array_of_samples())
    if a.channels == 2:
        y = y.reshape((-1, 2))
    if normalized:
        return a.frame_rate, np.float32(y) / 2**15
    else:
        return a.frame_rate, y

fs, data = read(file_path)

print("Tocando ...")


# Inicializar PyAudio
pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Abir stream
stream = pyaud.open(format =  pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels = 1,
                rate = fs,
                output = True)



x=0;
volume=1

#for até o final do áudio
for i in range(0, len(data), 4096):

    #capturando teclas no windows com python
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        aa = ord(msvcrt.getch())
        if aa == 0 or aa == 224:
            b = ord(msvcrt.getch())
            x = aa + (b*256)
    
    #seta para cima == 18656 incrementa volume
    if x == 18656:
        volume=volume+0.1;
        x=0;
    
    #seta para baixo == 20704 decrementa volume
    if x == 20704:
        if volume>0.1:
            volume=volume-0.1;
        x=0;

    #Cortando o áudio em um tamanho de 4096 samples e aplicando volume
    chunk = (data[i:i+4096]) * volume
    #garantindo que nenhum valor extrapole os limites do float point
    chunk=np.clip(chunk, -1, 1)
    #Codificando o áudio e enviando para o stream do pyaudio
    out = pack("%df"%len(chunk), *(chunk))
    stream.write(out)


#parando tudo
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
pyaud.terminate()
```

Um TO-DO pra vc:

Ao invés de decodificar todo o áudio e guardar ele inteiro na var `data` tente decodificar dentro do `for` pedaço por pedaço, isso te dará um ganho brutal no uso de memória e processamento...